# how to save the output of a loop

Tags: r, for-loop, output

i'm making a for loop to creates and modifiy dataframes, and now i want to save them to my computer.
I've tried with differents functions, but either way they don't save or just the last one is saved ( i have 66df). I'm new to R so maybe I'm missing something

my code looks like this

```
assign(paste0('output_df',sep = '_', i),df)
  
  write_csv(output_df, file = '/output/data frame.csv')
```

does the assign(past0 change something ?
do you have any idea what's wrong ?

Comment: Because your output filename is the same. Read about `paste`. Try something like `file = paste0("/output/dataframe_", i, ".csv")`

Comment: thanks, i've tried this and it worked perfectly !

Answer (score 1):

The name of the data frame can remain the same, it is the name of the file that should be changed.

By the time it gets to `write_csv()`, the value of `output_df` should be different each time, but the name `output_df` can (and normally would) remain the same. And then you can save it with a different file name each time:

`write_csv(output_df, file = paste0("/output/dataframe_", i, ".csv"))`